# "document.formName" is undefined?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've got an ASP.NET site running locally on my XP system using IIS Express. There is a live version of the site running on a Windows server.

In the web pages, often the Javascript will reference a form on the page using the style `document.formName`, where `formName` is the name of the form. As far as I know, this is a cross-browser method, along with `document.forms.formName` and `document.forms[0]` and so forth.

On my local development site, the reference `document.frm1` (I know, bad naming practice) errors out; it is undefined. On the other hand, `document.forms.frm1` works fine. Strangely, this doesn't occur on the server, although both pages are identical as far as the code goes. I've double checked with Firebug, and in both IE8 and Firefox 6.

Another weird part: checking with Firebug, `document.frm1` is undefined, but `document.frmClose` (another form) exists! Huh?!

Anyone experienced this before?

Comment: why all this pain when you can be cross browser and cross platform in a flash using JQuery? for example: $('#myForm') should give you the form... in all browsers.

Comment: Could we see the HTML?...Sounds like you have some invalid HTML.

Comment: @Davide Piras - you suggest he add tens of thousands of lines of javascript (jQuery) just to do what `document.getElementById` already does? Blindly adding a framework to your project just for the parts that duplicate standard functionality is Considered Harmful.

Comment: @Davide: Right, but it's not a browser issue; I'm using the _same_ browser, with the same HTML, same Javascript... and it errors out locally, but not on the server. I'm not concerned with how to fix it, it's trivial. I'm concerned with why it's happening in the first place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT 1**

I did some experimentation, and found that the `id` property is used for `document.forms`, whereas the `name` property seems to be used for `document.formName`

http://jsfiddle.net/GVjsv/

---

**Original Answer**

Ensure that your javascript is not executing before DOM is ready. One way to help is to put your javascript at the bottom of the page, or if you're using a framework be sure to wrap the code in a `ready`-type function:

jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Mootools: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/DomReady

Vanilla javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Code to be run.
}
```

The reason that this is inconsistent between servers could be that the local development server loads the page more quickly than the live server does. The timing works out so that you *usually* don't get the same error in both places - the emphasis is added because if you tried enough times, you would probably be able to reproduce the error in both places.

Comment: The only thing is, even if it was erroring because the DOM isn't ready, I went in with Firebug after the page finished loading, and `document.frm1` was still undefined, while `document.forms.frm1` worked. Would the Javascript error stop the DOM from loading completely?

Comment: Check out the edit, let me know if frm1 has both an `ID` and `NAME` property. As you see in the jsFiddle, if the name property is omitted then `document.formName` will not work.

Comment: Thanks for that. That is an interesting behavior. However, indeed, both the `id` and `name` values are set. I'll do some experimenting on the server, to see if I can somehow reproduce the error. There's really **no** difference in the code. It's identical on the server and locally. The server just doesn't error.

Comment: Hrm. I was sure I had it! :) Is there not any other difference... https/http, different URLs for the `action` property.... something *has* to be different. I don't know that those two latter items would cause this issue, just fishing.

Comment: Well, both are using `https`, however my local environment is just using a urlacl of the local port.

Comment: What is the urlacl? Can you post the form HTML (the entire `<form...` tag) for both the live and local? If that is the only difference, maybe there's something to that?

Comment: WOAH! Wait a minute! I just checked the code that's being rendered by ASP.NET, and indeed, the `form` on my local machine has no `name` property... The form has `runat="server"`, but why is the name getting stripped away?

Comment: Boom: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2011/04/12/asp-net-form-tag-doesn-t-have-name-attribute-xhtmlconformance.aspx - check the `xhtmlConformance` tag in your `web.config` files on both servers, as the article says, we should expect the one that *works* to have `Legacy` for this setting, which is apparently not the recommended setting but lets your app NOT conform to XHTML 1.1 guidelines (which does not allow the `name` attribute on form elements oO). Let me know :)

Comment: Nice!! And incidentally, right before I read your last message, I found the problem! Here's the catch: both my local and live sites have the same `web.config`. But, that article actually hints at an underlying issue: .NET! In the article, the customer had migrated their site from .NET 1.1 to 4.0. My live site runs on 2.0, so I checked the `applicationhost.config` of IIS Express, and BOOM. Turns out it was using `Clr4IntegratedAppPool` as the app pool under `applicationDefaults`. Changed it to `Clr2IntegratedAppPool`, and all is well! Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: This conversation reminds me again why I stick to php... I do not miss MS's IDE or environment, not one bit :P Glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 8):

To get the **name** attribute added to your **form** element you need to add...

```
<system.web>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" /> <!-- http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes -->
</system.web>
```

...to your **web.config**

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me.  I had an existing site with some old javascript in it that was using document.Form1.someTextField.value.  And it had stopped working after I rolled back the web.config file.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend not using the name attribute for JavaScript identification purposes. Instead, give the element an id and use

```
document.getElementById("elementId");
```

e.g.

```
<form id="form1"></form>
<script>
  var form = document.getElementById("form1");
</script>
```

Comment: old fashion JavaScript, JQuery or other cross browser JS libraries are useful and free and available :)

Comment: Some of the more fancy stuff (getElementsByClassname, etc) may not work in all browsers, but getElementById works in every major browser AFAIK. I love jQuery... when it's needed. But it isn't always needed, and the minute it takes me to look up the URL for the google-hosted version or download my code is a minute that I'm interrupting my flow when I'm in the 'zone'. To say nothing of adding weight to a page when it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is below:

***Just add a name property in form tag***

**If you are using below code**

```
<form id="form1"></form>
<script>
  var form = document.form1; //getting undefined error here
</script>
```

What you need to perform here is:

**add "name" property in form tag like below**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1"></form>
<script>
var form = document.form1; //Now it will work fine and provide the correct value
</script>
```