# DOM object is null when referenced by name (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom, iis-7, iis-8

We have some legacy applications running at our organization. These applications were built on ASP.NET 2.0. We recently upgraded our servers (from Windows 2008 to Windows 2012 / IIS 7 to IIS 8) and these legacy applications are part of the move as well.

The trouble occurs on IIS 8 in code where a DOM object is referenced as `document.Form1.textBoxID`. The applications were running fine on IIS 7 and on IIS 8 the applications throw error:

> Unable to get property 'textBoxID' of undefined or null reference

I tested the applications and `document.Form1` is `undefined` on applications running on IIS 8. On IIS 7 the same applications are running without any error. However, on the new IIS (8) when I changed the JavaScript to `document.getElementById('textBoxID')` it works.

My Question is, do I have to change any IIS setting to get the applications to work properly or do I need to change all the legacy apps to use `document.getElementById`?

Comment: `document.Form1.textBoxID` -- This will search for an element having name as `textBoxID` in a form named `Form1`. Are you sure that the HTML hasn't changed?

Comment: Yes the elements are named appropriately i.e. they use the name attribute with the appropriate name in the application, but it still doesn't work document.Form1 is coming as `undefined`

Comment: Does the form being rendered have the name `Form1` on it?

Comment: the form element doesn't have a name on it . It has ID attribute only. Can we use name element with Form as well?

Comment: When you use document.Form1 I believe it refers to the form name. Have a look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2011/04/12/asp-net-form-tag-doesnt-have-name-attribute-xhtmlconformance/

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["document.formName" is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436277/document-formname-is-undefined)